# Flutter GridView childAspectRatio dynamic content

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, gridview

[gridview / listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqQfx.png)

Previously I used a **ListView.builder** to show my list, which respects the height of the content *(image 3)*, however I need to show it in 2 columns with a **GridView**, unfortunately this no longer respects the height, that is why I made an exact calculation for the **childAspectRatio** *(image 1)*, knowing only that the size of the letter of the system is in *1.0*, but when enlarging it overflows out the container *(image 2)* and does not expand because the value of the *Ratio* is already static; for example:

```
final itemWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; 
double ratio;

if(isBigBox){
  ratio = (itemWidth / 117);
} else {
  ratio = (itemWidth / 50);
}

return GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  childAspectRatio: ratio,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: list.map((dynamic item) {
    return Boxes(
      item: item,
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```

I need to know how to handle the Ratio of a GridView in this way.
My goal is that the GridView element should take as little height as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe GridView is not what you are looking for. Have you considered https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view (https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredGridView/StaggeredGridView.count.html with shrinkWrap)?

Comment: Thank you, i used Tablet class and it works !

Comment: Super awesome, @DanielRoldán. Please don't forget to accept my answer or suggest how I can improve it.